# How to access its values in a AsyncTask class?

Tags: android, class, android-asynctask

This is my class:

```
class  InputTaskResult {
    int pos;
    String[] imagesurls;
}
```

And this is how I use it in my Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group){
    InputTaskResult inputtask=null;
    inputtask.pos=position;
    inputtask.imagesurls=imageIds;
    new LoginProgressTask().execute(inputtask);
```

And my AsyncTask called LogiProcessTask:

```
class LoginProgressTask extends AsyncTask<InputTaskResult,Void,Bitmap> {
..
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(InputTaskResult... input) {
    int post=input.pos; --error
    String[] urls=input.imagesurl;  --error
```

How can I access the values of my input? Everything I try gives me an eror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
int post=input[0].pos;
String[] urls=input[0].imagesurls;
```